# Remove the Analytical badge from the list of badges for sites where no users have them

Tags: feature-request, badges

I noticed that all Stack Exchange sites created after its retirement have the *Analytical* badge in the list of badges. But this badge has been retired and there are no users who already have it, or can earn it through account merges. E.g. for [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/77/analytical).

Is it possible to remove it for such sites?

[image: Analytical]

Comment: [Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com) is another site where no one has it.

Comment: Pretty sure the list is standard - some site were never in beta in the same way so no one ever could have gotten constable.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek in this case such list should be per site customizable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of badges is currently standard across all sites.  You can't earn bounty-related badges on a per-site meta either, yet the badges appear there, too ([example](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges)).  And some badges, like Beta, Precognitive, Sheriff, and Constable, appear on meta but can only be awarded on main.  But it appears that Convention has been special-cased to not appear on meta sites (where it can't be earned).  So yeah, unavailable badges are a little weird and inconsistent.

My earlier draft of this answer explained why special-casing this one badge would be messy, but IlmariKaronen pointed out a reasonable solution in the comments (and declined to write an answer):  If a badge can no longer be awarded on a site, *and* nobody has it, then exclude it from the list.

This way there is a rule in the code, not a bunch of per-site customizations.  If anybody has the badge, keep it on the list -- it says "retired", after all, and that way people won't wonder why their badges aren't there.  But if it's a "closed" badge and nobody already has it, there's no benefit to including it on the list.  This solution would address all badges for which this is true, not just Analytical.

Comment: Um... where do you see the Convention badge on meta sites? It's not in the list [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges), nor [on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Comment: The Precog & Beta badges are weird too. They are listed on the meta badge pages but only awarded on the main pages.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen whoops, you're right -- they seem to have special-cased that.  I changed my example; bounty badges appear on per-site metas but you can't award bounties on meta.

Comment: Given that nobody can earn Analytical any more, it would seem sensible to just hide it if nobody has it on that site. Ditto for Precognitive and Beta (since we can be pretty sure that any site where those badges *could* be earned will have at least one user who *has* earned them).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen hide if nobody has it, for badges that can't be earned, sounds like a good solution.  Are you going to write an answer suggesting that?  If not, I'll update mine to suggest that (with credit of course).

Comment: Feel free to update your answer. Although it seems to me that that's precisely what alexolut was suggesting above in the first place.

Comment: I read the question as being about one badge, but there's a larger problem -- and, now that you've pointed it out, a workable solution to that larger problem.

Comment: and you can't get precog, beta and constable badges on the original trilogy and probably SE 1,0 sites

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Precognitive is still kept in the list of badges on all sites in order to promote Area 51.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The Analytical badge can still be earned on sites where users have already earned it, by merging an older account with the badge into a newer one, which is why you still see the badge being awarded.

Comment: @gparyani: That's a point, although that's not really *earning* the badge so much as just moving it from one account to another. In any case, on new sites where nobody has it, it can't be "earned" that way, either.